# Can you transfer NXT assets directly to another nxt account?

Tags: nxt, decentralized-assets, mgw, multigateway

I purchased a few mgwBTC (multigateway bitcoins) and I want to be able to transfer them to my other account. Is this possible? Can someone take a snapshot of how this is done? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

In default NRS client this can be done via [Asset Exchange] -> [My Assets] -> [Transfer].

Comment: Do I need NXT to transfer the asset? To other NXT as asset?